# Why does my character walk forward automatically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm sure that I'm not alone. Sometimes when I go somewhere or build something, all of a sudden, the character keeps going forward just like the W is stuck. But it's not.

To recover from this I have to bash my ASWD keys on the keyboard (gently :P) and it's ok.  What's causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you on Linux? If so, then X is grabbing focus so the event is lost like badp said. Pressing escape always fixes it for me.

Comment: Please forgive my density, but what other window manager is there?

Comment: [X is not a window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), and I'm pretty sure that @Warface is using X. I doubt there is any other 3D-accelerated alternative to X, and that is compatible with Java.

Comment: @Denilson Ah window *system*. My point remains the same though: "What alternative is there to X"?

Comment: This is known among my friends as the "Linux Cruise Control" bug. It's both convenient and gets me killed, depending on the situation.

Comment: I've noticed this happening on Windows as well.

Comment: Has this happened to you as of late?

Comment: Had it 7 times yesterday, win7_64, last JRE_64, last_minecraft build. And some times before, since the first beta build.

Comment: Got coke spoiled on your keyboard?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a bug. It usually happens when I'm moving and clicking at the same time.

It has been reported on GetSatisfaction, and [there is a known workaround](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/stuck_keys_under_linux_unrelated_to_losing_focus_or_opening_the_inventory#reply_5439272): update `lwjgl` library that is downloaded together with Minecraft.

This bug has been around for a lot of time, and [it would be great if Mojang actually fixed it](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/lwjgl_on_linux_needs_to_be_updated)...

Comment: Awesome find!  I didn't realize Minecraft had control issues on Linux which don't afflict in on other OSes.  Here's hoping Mojang updates LWJGL before release, at least.

Answer (score 9):

One cause of this is when you press two keys at almost the same time, one of which is a movement key and the other opens a GUI.  A well-known "poor-man's autorun" in Minecraft is to press the "walk forward" and "inventory" keys at the same time.  You will begin walking — *with the inventory screen open* — and will continue walking after closing your inventory again, even though no key is held down.

Other input "collisions" may cause this as well, but as [badp points out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/annoying-auto-foward-in-minecraft/27805#27805), the only real after-the-fact solution is to press the "stuck" key again.  There is no way to *prevent* this kind of key-sticking, either, other than avoiding the simultaneous inputs which cause it.

Answer (score 7):

This probably means that Minecraft, for whatever reason, lost the "key W was released (thus the user wants to stop moving forwards)" event, and as a result you're still going forwards.

Try pressing W again.

Comment: This type of thing used to happen to me all the time with other games with an old keyboard I had. The keyboard wouldn't register more than four keys at once, so if I held down more than four keys it would forget that the W key was held down. Example: I was holding down the W key to move forward. I then pressed and held down the A key to strafe, the SHIFT key for a modifier, started pressing the E key for an attack and then pressed the space key to jump. This caused the game to continue the W key press until I pressed and released it again.

Comment: Pressing W again does nothing, I have to press space will pressing all ASWD together and it's ok...

Comment: Alternatively, try unplugging and replugging your keyboard.