# Why can't I stop running?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is driving me insane...I have been playing Minecraft for over a year on a different computer and now I'm playing it on my normal computer... anyway the issue is that when I hold down any key for too long on Minecraft doesn't register the key release.

For example if I hold w for ~2 seconds I'll keep going in that direction... same with spacebar etc...

I checked if the keys are getting stuck on my board and they are not....

Anyone have ideas?  It's annoying as hell.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the key a few times? If you keep pressing the key *and* your keyboard **isn't** actually stuck, eventually the keyRelease event should trigger.

Comment: @Raven that doesn't actually keep the initial problem from happening though.

Comment: If I press the key while it's doing the auto thing it stops but it'll start again if it's held again for 2 seconds

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: Is your task somehow losing focus? If you switch windows/tabs while in the game, it can cause the button release to not register.

Comment: i'm on windows7 64bit. I doubt it's losing focus. i'm not switching  between any other windows.

Comment: Have you tried with a different keyboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my character walk forward automatically?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/why-does-my-character-walk-forward-automatically) (linux, but still likely related)

Comment: This issue for me usually occurs in full screen mode. If you are running or doing any sort of movement and press F11, your player will continue running unless your player is attacked or looses a hunger bar.

Answer (score 5):

Check your keystroke repeat rate/repeat delay and turn it down if you have to. I used to run into the same thing back in the day when playing Unreal Tournament and it turned out that the keystroke repeat was kicking in and that was what was keeping me running in the same direction even though I would have different keys held down.

XP & Win7 both: Start > Control Panel > Keyboard

Comment: Nope not it. :( 

Think I may reformat my computer tomorrow and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @josipii That's a bit extreme. I'd highly recommend finding another keyboard and trying with that first.

Comment: I did. Same issue. No big deal...been meaning to reformat for the past 9 months haha. So much bloatware all over my computer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to update LWJGL. From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Update_LWJGL):

> http://lwjgl.org/download.php

> Select the latest stable release and download the lwjgl-X.X.X.zip. You should also backup your .minecraft folder before following the steps below. As a last resort, you can use the Minecraft Launcher's Force Update option to reset the files.

> - With 2.8.1, on most 64 bit computers, the lwjgl64.dll update will cause a black screen crash. You can revert to the backup version you have saved if needed.

- Again on several 64 bit computers, the OpenAL64.dll update can cause a sound glitch that makes bursting sounds. Keep a backup in case you need to rollback.
- Version 2.8.5 generally breaks shift-clicking; 2.8.4 and 2.9.0 do not. You can change the url in your browser to access 2.8.4 or 2.9.0 rather than 2.8.5.
- LWJGL 2.8.5 has a bug which sends a false signal that the user released all currently pressed keyboard keys when a mouse button is pressed. That means that your building will be significantly slower. Do not update to this version if this bothers you.

> This bug seems to be fixed when playing in fullscreen mode (Default <kbd>F11</kbd>), or updating to LWJGL 2.9.0.

Note that versions of Minecraft higher than release 1.6, the new launcher will automatically update LWJGL to newer versions, making the steps in this guide unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me a few times

In singleplayer: hit esc, then back to game.

In multiplayer: disconnect, then reconnect.

If that still does not work, check the delays between key strokes.

Answer (score 2):

This sometimes happens to me on my older computer (running Ubuntu) I don't have a problem on a more powerful Pc with Vista. It seemed to happen a lot when I had other processes running like the update manager. I would suggest making sure no other background processes are running and perhaps your PC is not powerful enough to keep up. Since the lighting model changed in 1.8 I have had this problem less - it was especially bad when day turned to night or vice versa and when it was raining!