# Minecraft Inventory Items moving strangely

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently I've been using the SE Gaming Minecraft server a lot, and today when I tried to craft watermelons into seeds, I discovered that they wouldn't move to the crafting table when I clicked them, they moved to my quick-use bar, then moved back to my inventory when I clicked them again. I checked my Shift key, and it was not compressed, so that's not the problem. What is the problem?

Comment: Do you use Linux? If so, you're having the ["Linux Cruise Control" bug](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/why-does-my-character-walk-forward-automatically), where a key gets stuck active.  In this case, shift.

Comment: there's a feature in windows called "sticky keys" check your accessibility options

Comment: @JohntheGreen That sounds like it should be an answer.

Comment: @Kevin Well, if he's not using Linux, it would be totally wrong, and if he is, it's a dupe of the question I linked.  :)

Comment: @ratchetfreak I *hate* sticky keys...

Comment: The "Linux Cruise Control" bug happens on Windows too, it's just not as common.

Comment: I think the "Linux Cruise Control" bug (in Windows, at least) is caused by the "Alt" key. I've used this bug before to afk climbing ladders (it did not end well).

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98303/minecraft-inventory-dragging-glitch

Comment: Have you turned touchscreen mode on lately? That might be a problem that's affecting you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you checked your shift key, but 1 explanation would be that you pressed shift multiple times resulting in an affect called sticky keys. One way to remove it is press shift repeatedly until your computer has a pop up message. Then you have to press cancel or something.

Sorry if this isn't specific enough.

Comment: How could someone "steal your credit" by editing?

Comment: @gnovice It's funny because that line is now gone.

Comment: You might want to read the FAQ here on the site and [on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) on how *reputation* (not credits) and the Stack Exchange engine works.

Comment: Because when someone edits it makes the awnser in their name

Comment: @ToazterWafflez: No, it doesn't. The answer still belongs to the person who first posted it, and they get all the Rep from votes. The person who edited it is simply listed *next to* them. I suggest taking a spin through the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) to get a better understanding of how it all works here.