# Minecraft inventory dragging glitch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I fix my Minecraft inventory? I am trying to select items, but ever since the recent update, I have to click on the item and drag it to my inventory. It isn't working to fast move it using shift either. Also when I go to the crafting table it won't let me separate the items only one at a time?

Comment: Go to options and turn touchscreen mode off.

Answer (score 8):

As @JeffreyLin said, this is as simple as turning touchscreen mode off in options:[image: Go to options and change <code>Touchscreen Mode</code> to off]

Comment: Oh THANK you! I turned touchscreen mode on to see if I could play with my touchscreen, and I forgot to turn it off! This made me lose in Hunger Games!!! I was afraid I'd have to make a new minecraft.jar

Comment: Thank you very much. I suffered from a genuine bug regarding this, I couldn't select a particualr slot at all and touchscreen mode was off. Turning off and on worked.