# Clicking pauses game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I hold the left click button the game goes to the pause screen. I have to click back to game a lot to mine and harvest trees. Does anybody know what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Clicking outside the game window will pause the game, though I'm not sure what might be causing this.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your computer. Try playing another game and see. Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: This happens to me all the time in minecraft classic. The game isn't even playable in Chrome. It's a little better in Internet Explorer _oh god I can't believe I just wrote those words_, but the bug still happens from time to time. Google shows me lots of people having this problem with minecraft on linux, but I am on windows. I gave up, never fixed it.

Comment: Are you on Linux?  Perhaps the solution [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/why-does-my-character-walk-forward-automatically) will help you?

Comment: It doesn't matter if he's on Linux because my bro has the same problem occasionally but he's on windows.

Comment: Are you playing in the browser? If you are, does installing it fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably due to your computer not being able to keep up its framerate.

Turn down your graphic options and view distance.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my bro said helped when he had the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Performance has nothing to do with it.  This is a common problem for lots of people, trying to play in browsers and most people do not have stuck <kbd>ESC</kbd> keys.

For most people, what is happening is some app (possibly the browser itself?) is stealing mouse focus, which causes the game to pause.  The pause is a nice feature for when you have to leave the browser game for a minute.  When you hit escape it pauses automatically while you do other things.  However, in this case some app seems to be grabbing mouse focus, which causes the game to pause.  It happens to me only when I hold down either right or left click.

A couple things to check:

- Chrome seems to do this a lot, try a different browser.
- Do you have an app running which refreshes itself every once in a while, or grabs focus? Examples:  an alarm, IM alerts, running a macro.
- Is your java up-to-date?  Minecraft runs in it, and depends on it being updated frequently.
- Is your escape key stuck?  It does happen, just give it a tap and make sure its working properly.

Comment: this has nothing to do with java, flash or browser, this is simply a glitch. the mouse focus was never stolen, i use 4 browsers and same issue, i re installed java and flash. this is just a random glitch, like i cant click, and this happens only when i click not randomly.